# installation of java using powershell does not work

Tags: java, powershell

I use the following command in powershell to install java using the jdk that I have

```
start-process -filepath jdk-x64.exe -passthru -wait -argumentlist "/s,INSTALLDIR=c:\progra~1\jre,/L,myinstallogs.log"
```

It just starts a process and never install java in program files
When I run PS command, all i see is a new process started but not the actual installation.
Not sure what am I doing wrong

Comment: Like this ? -ArgumentList “”, “”  Do I need /s?

Comment: `"like","this","instead"`

Comment: So if you run `jdk-x64.exe /s,INSTALLDIR=c:\progra~1\jre,/L,myinstallogs.log` from a command prompt, not from powershell, it works ok? Are you sure the commas are supposed to be there?